# Why is Chess so easy?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The Chess event of Karazhan was designed for a raid of 10 people during Burning Crusade. It was more or less a prototype vehicle fight like those introduced during Wrath of the Lich King. Those fights eventually received scaling based off the player's item level and with the help of equipment from later expansions, players became able to solo these fights.

As far as I can tell, the Chess event doesn't scale: the pieces' health, damage and cooldowns are fixed. Despite this, I can easily defeat the event on my own by controlling the Conjurer/Warlock and nothing else. Even before I perfected my strategy, my NPC pieces usually managed to kill the entire enemy board And I could defeat the enemy king without losing mine.

Did the mechanics of the Chess event change at some point? Were the other 9 players always this redundant?

Comment: What level is your character.  If your going in at level 90 of course it's easy...

Comment: @Ramhound: The Chess event doesn't scale off level nor iLevel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few hotfixes in 5.3 that made the Karazhan Chess Event easier:

http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/9687729/

> **Karazhan**
>
> - **Chess Event**: Increased the delay between moves for enemy chess pieces.
> - **Chess Event**: Medivh's buff to damage on chess pieces has been reduced to 100%, down from 200%.
> - **Chess Event**: Damage from Medivh's fire has been reduced to 4k, down from 10k.

Since the enemy pieces move slower than they used to, it's easier to dodge damage using the Water Elemental strategy. Also, since you take less damage from the fire, it technically makes the Water Elemental's AoE relatively stronger than it used to be (since the only other AoE damage was the fire).

Comment: Right.  As the content became irreverent and people still wanted to run the dungeon, they made it easier to solo - like they did with more trivial content.  Tempest Keep was designed for 25 players and involved looting "conjured" legendaries in order to even have a chance at success.  Now you can solo it with any level 85+

Comment: I believe the main reason for the nerf was because the final boss of Karazhan dropped a battle pet, but players were having difficulty getting to the boss.

Comment: I'm accepting this, because while it's true that people used to solo this event even when it was fresh, it's the nerfs to Medivh's cheating and his pieces' action rate that make it seem so unusually trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Chess event has always been something that could be soloed.  Even in BC.  There were numerous rogues who would stealth in for "Free Loot"